# Sharing Template across company accounts

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to share a Document Template from Company A with Company B?

I am using impersonation and creating an Envelope via API and starting it off with a document with a particular Template ID in the JSON (as well as other assorted data) that I am passing to the API. This works great as long as I am impersonating a user account in Company A, which is the company the template exists. As soon as I impersonate a user in Company B, I get an error when creating the Envelope that says:

> USER_LACKS_MEMBERSHIP

and then:

> The UserID does not have a valid membership in this Account. User is
> not an active member of the template's account.

Other than duplicating the template to each linked company, which would then have a different TemplateID for each of the links companies, not to mention the problems if an edit was needed across all of those templates, is there any other option you might have as a suggestion?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Silly way to end the day but I just figured out that someone had disabled the Company B impersonated user account in Company A. Re-enabling the user account gave it access to pull the needed template and the application is working again.

Thank you for any thought you put into this.